# React Native Android run Error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to run my project in android emulate, It show error red screen, but iOS run perfectly.

My screen just have a View that contain a text

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
    View,
    Text,
} from 'react-native'

const Test = ({navigation}) => {
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>Hola</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Test
```

and in the index.js call de screen

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Test from "./src/test"
AppRegistry.registerComponent('SanSilvestre', () => Test);
```

A screen shot

```
Attempted to redefine property 'padding'. (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:65166)

Attempted to redefine property 'padding'. (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:65166)
```

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1oPM.png)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a syntax error in your code where you are defining padding twice in the same object.